# Automatically insert string while user is typing

Tags: javascript

In Preferences: Code Hints, Dreamweaver has this option:

> Close tags: After typing the open tag's ">"

I am teaching html to students and have them write code in a textarea, (which isn't the greatest UI but is at least on my own website).

I'd like to insert the closing tag as soon as the user types the ">" to end the opening tag and keep the position of the cursor between the opening and closing tags.

```js
;(function() {
 var Variables = {}
 Variables.greaterThan = false
 $('[name=GuessName]').keypress(keypress)
 function keypress(myEvent) {
  if (myEvent.which === 62) {
   Variables.greaterThan = true
  }
 }
 $('[name=GuessName]').keyup(keyup)
 function keyup(myEvent) {
  if (Variables.greaterThan) {
   var myTextarea = $(this).val()
   var startingPosition = -1
   var length = myTextarea.length-1
   for (var i=myTextarea.length; i>= 0; i--) {
    if (myTextarea.substr(i,1) === '<') {
     startingPosition = i
     break
    }
   }
   if (startingPosition > -1) {
    myTextarea += '</' + myTextarea.substr(startingPosition+1,length)
    $(this).val(myTextarea)
   }
   Variables.greaterThan = false
   // position the cursor at the appropriate spot
  }
 }
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter &lt;h1>
<textarea name="GuessName"></textarea>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Judging by your reputation, I assume you already know about the [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and why previous attempts are important in a question.

Comment: Are you asking how to turn a `textarea` into an HTML IDE?  Seems a bit broad...

Comment: Ouch. OK, back to the drawing board.

Comment: Well, I'd be happy with just closing the opening tag and that's all.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-textarea/input-selectionstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've chosen to provide an vanilla javascript response, a live demonstration of which may be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/Tomboyo/f8nLfwmn/6/

To begin, we attach an event listener to the textarea bound to the 'keyup' event. When the event fires, it finds the current cursor position using the `getStrPos` function (really just a modified cut of the function found in the article linked below). We then get the text to the left of the cursor position (but only up to 50 characters to the left, since we don't expect html tags to be that long and, frankly, we don't want to be running regexp searches on a massive blob of text).

The 'this' keyword in this block refers to the textarea:

```
    var pos = getStrPos('myArea');
    var retrotext = this.value.slice(Math.max(0, pos - 50), pos);
    var m = retrotext.match(/(?:<\/?)([^<>]+)(?:>)/g);
```

The `blacklist` variable defined next  in the script lists the names of tags that should not be closed (such as the `<br>` and `<input>` tags). This list is currently non-exhaustive; update it as you see fit.

```
var blacklist = ['input', 'br', 'hr'];
```

This final section prunes any found tags matching the blacklist entries and also prevents inserting closing tags to already closed tags. We assume that all tags become closed as the user types, so if the preceding tag is a closing tag, the cursor is misplaced or the '>' character is, in this case, erroneous. The `insertAfterCaret` function is something I found online. I mentioned earlier that `getStrPos` is based on this function, so an understanding of both can be gleaned from the article I cite at the foot of this answer.

```
    } else {
        //blacklist pruning
        for (var i = 0; i < blacklist.length; i++) {
            if (m[m.length - 1] == '<'+blacklist[i]+'>') {
                return;
            }
        }
        insertAfterCaret('myArea', m[m.length - 1].slice(0, 1) + "/" + m[m.length - 1].slice(1));
    }
```

Insert at Cursor (and derivatives) can be found here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20110102112946/http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/425/how-to-insert-text-into-a-textarea-where-the-cursor-is/

**UPDATE**
The sixth revision prevents the user from re-closing a closed tag while editing inside of it. it now does a forward-check (up to 50 characters away) to find a closing tag matching the opening tag to the left. if there is one, the '>' being typed is probably erroneous, and so a tag will not be inserted.

```
        var anterotext = this.value.slice(pos, Math.min(pos + 50, this.value.length));
        var closeTag = m[m.length - 1].slice(0, 1) + "/" + m[m.length - 1].slice(1);
        var n = anterotext.match(closeTag);
        if (n) { return; }
        insertAfterCaret('myArea', closeTag);
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomboyo. This is the reason I ask questions like this.  Your answer is so very different than how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
;(function() {
 var Variables = {}
 Variables.greaterThan = false
 $('[name=GuessName]').keypress(keypress)
 function keypress(myEvent) {
  if (myEvent.which === 62) {
   Variables.greaterThan = true
  }
 }
 $('[name=GuessName]').keyup(keyup)
 function keyup(myEvent) {
  if (Variables.greaterThan) {
   selectionStart = this.selectionStart
   var myTextarea = $(this).val()
   var startingPosition = -1
   for (var i=selectionStart; i>= 0; i--) {
    if (myTextarea.substr(i,1) === '<') {
     startingPosition = i
     break
    }
   }
   if (startingPosition > -1) {
    firstHalf = myTextarea.substr(0,selectionStart)
    middle = '</' + myTextarea.substr(startingPosition+1,selectionStart-startingPosition-1)
    secondHalf = myTextarea.substr(selectionStart,999)
    myTextarea = firstHalf + middle + secondHalf
    $(this).val(myTextarea)
   }
   Variables.greaterThan = false
   this.setSelectionRange(selectionStart,selectionStart)
  }
 }
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter &lt;h1>
<textarea name="GuessName"></textarea>
```